# Как в form action перейти не только в файл, но и в функцию

Tags: php

Как в `form`'e где `action=""` перейти не только в `php` файл, а и выбрать нужную функцию? То есть, имеем запись вида:

**Сама формочка**

```
<form method="post" action="../function/plusdays.php?id=plusTime">
    <input type="text" name="time">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

**И саму функцию :**

```
function PlusTime(){

    $plusTime   = $_POST['time'];

    echo "$plusTime";

    return;
}
```

---

Как же, не только открыть в `action` этот файл, но и войти в нужную мне функцию?

Comment: Если `action` нужно оставить пустым то добавь в форму скрытие `input` и в обработчике в зависимости от значения скрытого инпута переходи в нужную функцию.

Comment: Можно немного кода? Понял что нужно `<input type="hidden" name="функция">` А дальше не особо врубился

Comment: Написал подробный ответ с примером.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример того что я написал в комментарии:

Это ваша форма со скрытым `input`

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="time" />
    <input type="hidden" name="actionFunc" value="PlusTime" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

А это файл обработчика:

```
if(isset($_POST['actionFunc'])){
    $action_func = $_POST['actionFunc'];
    if (function_exists($action_func)){
        $action_func(); //Здесь вызов функции в нашем случае PlusTime;
    }
    else{
        //Если нет вашего метода то какая то логика
    }
}
else{
    //Если нет скрытого поля то какая то другая логика
}

function PlusTime(){

    $plusTime   = $_POST['time'];

    echo "$plusTime";

    return;
}
```

Comment: Реализация довольно хорошая, но за день, если не найдётся ещё решений, то отмечу это лучшим.

Comment: @MoloF Это ваш выбор, но как я понимаю если `action` пустой то другого варианта нету, все ровно надо на сервер отправить какой то ключ для выбора метода, и я другой вариант не знаю))))

Answer (score 2):

//HTML

```
<form method="post" action="../function/plusdays.php">
    <input type="text" name="time">
     <input type="hidden" name="actionFunc" value="plusTime">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

//PHP

```
  class methodes{
    function plusTime(){
        $this->plusTime  = $_POST['time'];
    }
    }

if(isset($_REQUEST)){
$func = new methodes;
$func->{$_REQUEST['actionFunc']};
}
```

**UPD**
Можно ещё так.

//PHP

```
  class methodes{
    function plusTime(){
        $plusTime   = $_POST['time'];
        echo $plusTime;
        return;
    }
    }

function myMethod($method){
return $method;
}

if(isset($_REQUEST)){
$func = new methodes;
$func->myMethod($_REQUEST['actionFunc']);
}
```

Какая между ними разница ? Узнайте ответ сами на практике! Это важно знать

**UPD 2 , Без ООП**

```
$function = 'test';
function myMethod($method){
return $method;
}
function test(){
    echo 'Yes!!!';
}
if(function_exists(myMethod($function)()))myMethod($function)();//Yes!!!
else die('hack atemp');
```

Comment: Оператор ${} рассматривается как переменная, имя которой определено как строка

Comment: Прочтите эту статью , конкретнее про оператор ${} 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/39034/

Comment: вы не _Delphinum_ случайно? ))